# Linked Geospatial Data in WFS

Tags: geospatial, releasing-data, linked-data, 5-star-scheme, inspire

At the Swedish University of Agricultural Sciences we have released some data based on the requirements of the INSPIRE directive.

We use Geoserver which provides us with a number of standard services. An example can be seen in the data's [WMS service](http://inspire2-1.slu.se:8080/geoserver/inspire_riksskogstaxeringen/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=inspire_riksskogstaxeringen:ForestVariables&styles=&bbox=276751.545,6137440.0,917384.248,7615120.0&width=221&height=512&srs=EPSG:3006&format=application/openlayers).

We're interested in the 5-star model for open/linked data and from what I understand we'd see this as 3-star data.

How can we go from here into the realm of linked data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP-URI values from controlled vocabularies in the attributes of your WMS datasets, as properties in your WFS feature types and WCS coverages.  You can additionally add links in your GetCapabilities response documents through metadata urls, and data urls...  And finally you can make links in your metadata documents for your services and datasets.